# Convert JSON into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a below JSON object that is retrieved by a query

```
r = {'metaData': [{'columnAliases': ['ltp', 'mcap', 'wsma30uptrend','15 day contraction'],
     'availableLimit': 477,
     'maxRows': 1,
     'isTrend': True,
     'limit': 2,
     'groups': ['symbol'],
     'tradeTimes': [1692210600000],
     'lastUpdateTime': 1692266340000}],
     'groups': ['BALRAMCHIN', 'GHCL'],
     'time': 138,
     'groupData': [{'name': 'BALRAMCHIN',
                    'results': [{'ltp': [394.6]}, {'mcap': [7938.8328]}, {'wsma30uptrend': [1]}, {'15 day contraction': [9.478]}]},
                   {'name': 'GHCL',
                    'results': [{'ltp': [516.1]}, {'mcap': [5048.8412]}, {'wsma30uptrend': [1]}, {'15 day contraction': [9.5524]}]}]}
```

I am having very tough time converting this JSON into a Pandas Dataframe that looks like below. groupData is the block from above JSON that need to be converted as below.

**Expected Output:**

```
name        ltp         mcap        wsma30uptrend   15 day contraction
BALRAMCHIN  394.6       7938.83     1               9.478
GHCL        516.1       5048.84     1               9.5524
```

My solution is as below which seems like a very crude way of doing this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(r['groupData'])
df = pd.concat([df.drop(['results'], axis=1), df['results'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
for i in range(0, 4):
    df = pd.concat([df.drop([i], axis=1), df[i].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
df = df.explode('ltp')
df = df.explode('mcap')
df = df.explode('wsma30uptrend')
df = df.explode('15 day contraction')
```

Can there be a better and simpler solution than this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. `df = pd.json_normalize(r, 'groupData',)` 2. `dfd = df.results.explode().apply(pd.Series).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))` 3. `dfd.explode(dfd.columns.tolist())`

Comment: I am using a older version of Pandas because of which I cannot use explode on list of columns. I have used the below statement instead of explode.

`dfd[list(dfd.columns)] = dfd[list(dfd.columns)].apply(lambda x: x.str[0])`

Also, your solution doesnt contain column 'name'. I have used the below statement to add the 'name' column.

`dfd = pd.merge(df['name'], dfd, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)`. Both these statements are taken from other solutions given below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without using the extra pandas functions like `explode`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for xx in r['groupData']: 
    d_ = {'name': xx['name']}
    for x in xx['results']:
        d_.update(x)
    df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(d_)])
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'name': {0: 'GHCL'},
 'ltp': {0: 516.1},
 'mcap': {0: 5048.8412},
 'wsma30uptrend': {0: 1},
 '15 day contraction': {0: 9.5524}}
```

Comment: Ooh after posting this, I noticed that Amira had posted something similar while I was drafting my answer....

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution. Your solution works great and scalable even when columns change. Is it possible to avoid for loop?

Comment: @SurajShourie no worries ! sometimes people can think in the same way ;)

Answer (score 0):

I made a df by directly iterating (single loop) through the original JSON object and forming a dictionary that matches the desired DataFrame structure where I removed the  `explode`, `concat`, and `drop`, I know they can sometimes be computationally expensive and increase your code complexity.

```
import pandas as pd

r = {
    'groupData': [
        {'name': 'BALRAMCHIN',
         'results': [{'ltp': [394.6]}, {'mcap': [7938.8328]}, {'wsma30uptrend': [1]}, {'15 day contraction': [9.478]}]},
        {'name': 'GHCL',
         'results': [{'ltp': [516.1]}, {'mcap': [5048.8412]}, {'wsma30uptrend': [1]}, {'15 day contraction': [9.5524]}]}
    ]
}

data = []
for group in r['groupData']:
    row = {'name': group['name']}
    for result in group['results']:
        for key, value in result.items():
            row[key] = value[0]
    data.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['name', 'ltp', 'mcap', 'wsma30uptrend', '15 day contraction']
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution. Your solution also looks great and wondering if for loops can be avoided. Having said that I have made a small change to avoid hard coding column names.

Answer (score 0):

Column names are in `columnAliases`, `explode` method is not needed.

```py
import pandas as pd
r = {...}

# Get columns name
columns = r['metaData'][0]['columnAliases']

# Get data
data = []
for group_data in r['groupData']:
    # Get name column
    row_data = [group_data['name']]
    for result in group_data['results']:
        value = list(result.values())[0][0]
        row_data.append(value)
    data.append(row_data)

# Load df
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name'] + columns)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
         name    ltp       mcap  wsma30uptrend  15 day contraction                            
0  BALRAMCHIN  394.6  7938.8328              1              9.4780                            
1        GHCL  516.1  5048.8412              1              9.5524
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution. Your solution works great and scalable even when columns change. Is it possible to avoid for loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use json_normalize and without explode, you can traverse the path groupData.results, then use bfill / ffill to fill the NaNs and drop the duplicates.

```
>>> df = pd.json_normalize(r, record_path=["groupData", "results"], meta=[["groupData","name"]]).bfill().ffill().rename(columns={'groupData.name':'name'}).drop_duplicates('name', keep='first')
>>> df
       ltp         mcap wsma30uptrend 15 day contraction        name
0  [394.6]  [7938.8328]           [1]            [9.478]  BALRAMCHIN
4  [516.1]  [5048.8412]           [1]           [9.5524]        GHCL
```

Since the values from the original is array we can just get the first member of the array from the affected columns.

```
>>> cols = ['ltp', 'mcap', 'wsma30uptrend', '15 day contraction']
>>> df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str[0])
>>> df
     ltp       mcap  wsma30uptrend  15 day contraction        name
0  394.6  7938.8328              1              9.4780  BALRAMCHIN
4  516.1  5048.8412              1              9.5524        GHCL
```